# How to turn off hybrid shutdown in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, wake-on-lan

Seems that unchecking "Turn on fast startup (recommended)" in power management is not working for me.

I'd like to use Wake On LAN and when I just power off my PC I can send magic packet and wake up the machine, but when I shutdown from Windows the PC won't power up. Unchecking above doesn't change it. WOL is enabled in device manager network adapter. What else can I do to turn off fast startup/hybrid shutdown?

Comment: Does your computer/motherboard actually support WOL?  If so, is it enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 As I said, it works fine when I just power off computer without using Windows. If I just press and hold power button and it powers down I can wake it up using WOL without a problem.

Comment: Hmm I apparently misread that.  ;) What method are you using to "power off" where WOL works?

Comment: Disable hibernation feature, see if that solves it. type "powerconfig -h off" in the command prompt, no quotes, hit enter.